# d3 graph duplicates on the DOM when data source changes

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am trying to create a line graph with D3. The data source will be updated on the user actions.

```
 <svg class="line-chart"></svg>


DataSource.watch("pdg2", (data) => {


function drawChart(data) {
var svgWidth = 800, svgHeight = 400;
var margin = { top: 20, right: 20, bottom: 30, left: 50 };
var width = svgWidth - margin.left - margin.right;
var height = svgHeight - margin.top - margin.bottom;

var svg = d3.select('svg')
    .attr("width", svgWidth)
    .attr("height", svgHeight);

var g = svg.append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

var x = d3.scaleTime()
    .rangeRound([0, width]);

var y = d3.scaleLinear()
    .rangeRound([height, 0]);

var line = d3.line()
    .x(function(d) { return x(d.date)})
    .y(function(d) { return y(d.value)})
    x.domain(d3.extent(data, function(d) { return d.date }));
    y.domain(d3.extent(data, function(d) { return d.value }));

g.append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
    .call(d3.axisBottom(x))
    .select(".domain")
    .remove();

g.append("g")
    .call(d3.axisLeft(y))
    .append("text")
    .attr("fill", "#000")
    .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)")
    .attr("y", -45)
    .attr("dy", "0.71em")
    .attr("text-anchor", "end")
    .text("ALLOC_GAS_VOL_MMCF");

g.append("path")
    .datum(data)
    .attr("fill", "none")
    .attr("stroke", "steelblue")
    .attr("stroke-linejoin", "round")
    .attr("stroke-linecap", "round")
    .attr("stroke-width", 1.5)
    .attr("d", line);
}

drawChart(data);

});
```

When the data source changes, it duplicates the same graph on the previous one. I was wondering if there is a way to check axes before its pushed to the graph?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add the line at start of function drawChart. It will remove all the elements inside svg.

d3.selectAll("svg > *").remove();

I have shown you where you need to write.

```js
function drawChart(data) {
  d3.selectAll("svg > *").remove();
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @Jasdeep Singh